# find the value of the div then PLUS that numeric value to another div

Tags: javascript

I have 2 div's.

One is SHIPPING and another is TOTAL PRICE.

```
<div id="tt_shipping_rate_basket">$0.00</div> = SHIPPING

<div class="op_col5_3" align="right" id="tt_total_basket">$897.00</div> = TOTAL PRICE
```

Also there are 4 inputs for SHIPPING, each adds it's own price in the shipping div..

for example:

input 1 = 10$

input 2 = 20$

so when choosing an input the value in the #tt_shipping_rate_basket is changing ajax to the value of the input... this works great...

The problem is, I do not want 2 divs (one for shipping and one for total price)...

I just want ONE div, called Total Price, and when I choose an input, the value should ADD&CHANGE to the #tt_total_basket instead of tt_shipping_rate_basket...

What I'm trying to do is, GET the value of SHIPPING field (which is ajax populated), GET the value of TOTAL PRICE field, then just ADD shipping to Total Price...

here is what I tried to write but it doesn't seem to work, sorry I'm not to good at programming..

```
function plus() {

var spTotal = document.getElementById("tt_total_basket");
var spShip = document.getElementById("tt_shipping_rate_basket");

spTotal = spTotal.innerHTML = +spShip;

}
```

spTotal is the TOTAL PRICE

spShip is the Shipping Price

The result should be (spTotal = spTotal.value + spShip.value)..

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Rather than innerHTML, it may be better to use [*textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) (or feature test and use *innerText* for IE browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but you get the idea:

```
var spTotal = document.getElementById("tt_total_basket").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var spShip = document.getElementById("tt_shipping_rate_basket").innerHTML.replace('$', '');

spTotal = parseFloat(spTotal) + parseFloat(spShip);
```

Comment: You'd need to do `spTotal.innerHTML = "$" + parseFloat(spTotal) + parseFloat(spShip);`